# Haskell version of Idris !-notation (bang notation)

Tags: haskell, idris

I've had the luxury of learning a bit of Idris lately and one thing I've found extremely convenient is the [`!`-notation](https://idris2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorial/interfaces.html?highlight=do%20notation#notation), which let's me shorten monadic code inside a do block such as

```
a' <- a
b' <- b
c' <- c
someFunction a' b' c'
```

to the much nicer

```
someFunction !a !b !c
```

Now when I write code in Haskell, I'm looking for something similar but as far as I can tell it doesn't exist (and the bang character is obviously already used for  strict pattern matching). Is there any way to avoid having a bunch of trivial left arrows inside a do block?  Perhaps an extension that adds a rewriting rule, or something to that effect?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Since every monad is an `Applicative` (with GHC >= 7.10) we can write

```
someFunction <$> a <*> b <*> c
```

Note that if `someFunction` returns a monadic value of type `m T`, the above will return `m (m T)`, which is likely not what we want (as @pigworker points out below). We can however `join` the two layers together:

```
join $ someFunction <$> a <*> b <*> c
```

Comment: Perfect answer, exactly what I needed.  I guess I need to spend a bit more time with Applicative.  Thanks.

Comment: What is the type of `someFunction`? Is its return type monadic?

Answer (score 6):

An alternative to @chi's answer is [`liftA3 someFunction a b c`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.1.0/docs/Control-Applicative.html) (with `join` if needed).

Answer (score 2):

Speaking of arrows...

```
import Control.Arrow

a' = Kleisli $ const a
b' = Kleisli $ const b
c' = Kleisli $ const c

foo = (`runKleisli`()) $
  (a' &&& b') &&& c' >>> uncurry (uncurry someFunction)
```

Not that I recommend this.