# Proper way of applying two (or many) option values to a function in F#

Tags: haskell, f#, functional-programming, ocaml

Recently I discovered a style of programming which is very useful (and pretty) in functional world called [Railway oriented programming](https://fsharpforfunandprofit.com/rop/).
For example when want to create a pipeline of functions that produce option type, and we want to return None if any of them fails we can do something like this:

```
someOptionValue // : 'a option
>>= func1       // func1: 'a -> 'b option
>>= func2       // func2: 'b -> 'c option
and so on...
```

where `(>>=) : 'a option -> (a' -> 'b option) -> 'b option` operator applies a value to the left hands side if it's `Some value` or `None` otherwise.

But, here is my problem, what if we have a function that "takes" two (or many) option types, let say `funcAB : 'a -> 'b -> 'c option`, `valA : 'a option` and `valB : 'b option` and we still want to create this pipeline or use some nice operator (not create a new one specifically for this, but use some standard approach, in particular I don't want to use `match ... with` to "unpack" option values)

Currently I have something like this:

```
valA
>>= (funcAB >> Some)
>>= (fun ctr -> valB >>= ctr)
```

But is doesn't seem 'correct' (or fun is the better word ;] ), and it doesn't scale well if a function takes more parameters or we want to create a longer pipeline. Is there a better way to do this?

I've used F# syntax but I think this question can be applied to any functional programming language, like OCaml and Haskell.

**EDIT (Solution):**

Thanks to the chi's answer I've created following code F# which is much more idiomatic then what I previously had:

```
funcAB <!> valA <*> valB |> Option.flatten
```

And it looks well if we have more values: `funcAB <!> valA <*> valB <*> valC <*> ...`.

I've used operators defined in [YoLo](https://github.com/haf/YoLo).

Comment: For your types you can use basic application `funcAB valA valB`, but something tells me you didn't intend `funcAB` to take options as input (?). Can you clarify?

Comment: So image that funcAB is a function from 3rd party api and it doesn't take option type, and even if it did it would need to handle option values (like a constructor that can create object only if all arguments are Some). EDIT: Yes, funcAB shouldn't take option types, I've corrected this.

Comment: Ok, I'd suggest you edit your question accordingly, fixing the input types to be non-options.

Comment: FYI: There's also `Option.map2` and `Option.map3` that can help. But there's no `Option.map4` which means Applicative is the way to go in the general case IMO. In addition, in F# it's somewhat frowned upon using operators (I personally don't agree with this, just saying). Therefore a possibly more F# idiomatic way is to use `|>`: `pure funcAB |> ap valA |> ap valB`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Haskell, we can use `Applicative` syntax for that:

If

```
valA :: f a
valB :: f b
funAB :: a -> b -> f c
```

then

```
join $ funAB <$> valA <*> valB :: f c
```

provided `f` is a monad (like `Maybe`, Haskell's `option`).

It should be adaptable to F# as well, I guess, as long as you define your operators

```
(<$>) ::   (a -> b) -> f a -> f b
(<*>) :: f (a -> b) -> f a -> f b
join  :: f (f a) -> f a
```

The above trick is a poor man's version of [Idris !-notation (bang notation)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33219871/3234959).

Another common option is using `do`

```
do a <- valA
   b <- valB
   funAB a b
```

but this is comparable with using `>>=`, indeed:

```
valA >>= \a ->
valB >>= \b ->
funAB a b
```

is not much more complex.

Answer (score 2):

One option is to use [computation expressions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/fsharp/language-reference/computation-expressions). For `option` there is no standard one but you can easily create your own:

```
type OptionBuilder() =
    member this.Bind (x, f) = Option.bind f x
    member this.Return x = Some x

let optional = OptionBuilder()

let a, b = Some(42), Some(7)
let f x y = x + y

let res = optional {
    let! x = a
    let! y = b
    return f x y
}
```

which closely resembles Haskells `do` notation.
For more advanced features, have a look at [F#+](http://gusty.github.io/FSharpPlus/) which also has a generic applicative functor operator `<*>`.